# I'm looking for wheels for my car (first time buyer). Why isn't anybody saying what the full bolt pattern is?

Tags: wheels

I'm looking online for used wheels for sale. I need wheels with bolt pattern 5x98 for my Alfa Romeo 156.

Almost nobody is actually writing what the full bolt pattern is. They all seem to write "5" if it's got 5 bolts, but the second part of the pattern is never present.

Here's an example of what most ads look like for me (I'm from Denmark:) I have circled the part where they are writing the bolt pattern (="krydsmål"). As you can see, they say 5, but not the other part.

How am I supposed to know whether they fit on my car when they won't specify the second part of the bolt pattern?

[image: img]

Comment: Quick anecdote: some car models are sold with 4 wheel lugs and 5 wheel lugs depending on year or engine, etc.  When people sell wheels for these models, the number of lugs can actually be the only important thing you need to know.  Outside of these exceptions it is frustrating tho.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is how used wheel and tire listings tend to be - missing a lot of important fitment information... You'll just have to contact the seller and ask them for the details directly. Or, if they mention what car it fits or the car it came off of (it looks like he mentions Mazda in the listing you posted), then you can check the bolt pattern for that car and see if it matches your car.

The only other reliable option, if perhaps the seller doesn't know the information you're asking for, is to go and physically measure or check the wheel against your own. I wouldn't base judgement off of the pictures alone, because due to the angle/perspective, it's usually very difficult or impossible to get the exact size.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are more likely to find a buyer if you don't specify the bolt pattern because you end up advertising to a larger market.  Of course if does mean someone may buy wheels which won't fit their car but as the seller, you sold your wheels and didn't misrepresent them.

Don't forget, it isn't just the PCD you'll need to check.  You need to check offset, centre bore, wheel width, etc...

You may also find it possible to fit 5x100 wheels using "wobble" bolts.

Remember, you don't have to simply buy a set of wheels, you can always ask the seller the question of what they actually fit.